# jlink This device cannot start. (Code 10) in win7 after update driver

Tags: usb, arm, drivers

I have one J-link ARM programmer, SO for first time i  start it via KEIL software, and  KEIL updated it's Driver, So after driver Updated , it's made crazy!!! and the led of its got down , so when i have  this error in KEIL :

***Cannot read jlink version number***

[image]

and via windows7 driver  manager i got this error:

***This device cannot start. (Code 10)***

[image]

So what i must to do for reinstalling it's proper Driver and so on?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I feel your only sensible recourse is to the vendor in this case.

Comment: Your are right, but the vendor is post pounding us instead of answer to this question!!!

Comment: Please use proper English spelling, capitalization, punctuation, etc.

Comment: This is a fake J-link or a genuine one?

Comment: This is a cloned j-link version!!!